# Publish Visual Studio 2010 web application to localhost

Tags: asp.net, web

I created a new web application in visual studio 2010.

I tried to publish it to the same computer (localhost) Windows7 64 bit/IIS7

No luck

I read some remarks from others, I also tried to specify the machine name instead of localhost.

I also tried creating a web setup project...

When I "surf" to localhost , I get the IIS7 welcome screen.

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to publish it, just point the virtual directory in iis to your source code.

Comment: thanks - 

Should I create a new virtual directory (add)?

When I do that - it is already asking for the physical path.

What should be the value of it ?

The location of the DLL or the location of default.aspx

Comment: the the parent folder of the default.aspx, the dll should be in a subfolder of that parent in the bin

Answer (score 0):

To host your web application, firstly you need to publish the app to a desired location; after publishing, then open IIS Manager(type "inetmgr" in run and hit enter) and go through sites path from the left panel and then right click on the sites and select "Add website"; In the next step, Add Website form will be opened asking you to enter some details; Enter the sitename, link the physical path to where you previously published and lastly give the port num; If you want to open that website in the port 80 itself, leave it as 80 and then click OK.. You can now browser your published web application... :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer - 

I did publish it but when I did that - it did not "publish" the dll only but all the source code - which is not what I wanted

How do I publish only the DLL (and maybe web.config...) ?